# Why doesn't AForge.Net BlobCounter.GetObjectsInformation() detect objects?

Tags: .net, computer-vision, aforge

I am trying to use AForge.Net for detecting rectangles in images. In a test image (appended below), I have the following code.

```
        BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();

        blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;

        blobCounter.MinHeight = 5;
        blobCounter.MinWidth = 5;
        blobCounter.MaxHeight = 5000;
        blobCounter.MaxWidth = 5000;


        blobCounter.ProcessImage(currentImage);

        Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();

        // check for rectangles
        SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();
```

However, the `GetObjectsInformation()` only returns one `Blob`, the whole picture. Why can't it detect the inner rectangles? I followed the examples but don't know where it's wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Image
[image: Simple test image.]

EDIT: OK. I found that if I store the image as PNG format, then it can detect the rectangles. But if I store the image as JPG format, then it fails. I am not sure what is the reason for this. I guess it's because of the loss of information of Jpeg format. I loaded the image to a `Bitmap` before processing.

Comment: I guess something is wrong with your JPG to Bitmap conversion then, Jpg compression should not be an issue here.
Any reason why your max blob dimensions are bigger than your image dimensions?

Comment: @Piglet Well, I set the max blob dimensions just to test it (I do want to use it in actual applications but in this example, I just want to make sure that it doesn't matter). I load the image by using `image = new Bitmap(input);` where image is a Bitmap and input is a FileStream. I also display the loaded images to an WPF Image control (with necessary conversions) and I can see no visual differences.

Comment: if your max blob size is smaller than the image dimensions then you shouldn't be able to find the entire image as a blob.

Comment: @Piglet Yes, but it will return zero object being detected.

Answer (score 3):

before searching for blobs you have to pre-process the image because blob counter searches for white objects withing black background in thresholded pictures (pixels are either pure white or pure black) and you are getting one blob because of the white background is counted as one blob (whole picture) so first you have to do some steps

1. Grayscale Image (color to gray scale)
2. Threshold Image (gray scale to white and black)
3. invert the Image (to convert the rectangle border to white)
4. Search for blobs

   ```
   public Bitmap PreProcess(Bitmap bmp)
   {
       //Those are AForge filters "using Aforge.Imaging.Filters;"
       Grayscale gfilter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
       Invert ifilter = new Invert();
       BradleyLocalThresholding thfilter = new BradleyLocalThresholding();
       bmp = gfilter.Apply(bmp);
       thfilter.ApplyInPlace(bmp);
       ifilter.ApplyInPlace(bmp);
       return bmp;
   }
   ```

call this method to prepare your image for blob searching

```
blobCounter.ProcessImage(PreProcess(currentImage));
```